# IE7 pass through windows authentication with IIS 8.5 unpredictable

Tags: internet-explorer, authentication, iis, iis-8

We've been rolling out our new web application from Windows 2003 w/II6 to Windows 2012R2 w/IIS 8.5, and the problem we're having is our internal app relies on IE pass through authentication.

We are in the process of upgrading everyone on to Windows 7 / IE10, but until that process completes what we're finding is that IE7 users now and then become unrecognized at the IIS side of things. If they restart their browser it continues working... so it's an inconvenience that would be nice to solve.

I've trolled through the settings, but with Win 2012 many features are a la carte installation, so I'm thinking there might be another module I need to add.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks!!